# How to check who has access to my ubuntu 20.04 system?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, google-chrome

I suspect that someone might have access to my Ubuntu system, because whenever I am doing something important such as typing a lot of unsaved text or training a deep learning model(in the cloud using chrome) the Chrome browser crashes. I know this might just be a bug in chrome but this thing was also happening when I was using Windows 10. So I switched to Ubuntu (dual boot) because windows 10 suddenly got very slow and laggy.

So to investigate I ran some commands of the internet on the Ubuntu OS and I believe I found some weird behavior. Please have a look at this text from the terminal which I got after I ran some command for user logins-

```
Nov 29 06:13:12 shivam-X510UNR PackageKit: uid 1000 is trying to obtain org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh auth (only_trusted:0)
Nov 29 06:13:12 shivam-X510UNR PackageKit: uid 1000 obtained auth for org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Nov 29 06:15:52 shivam-X510UNR pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Nov 29 06:15:52 shivam-X510UNR pkexec[143327]: shivam: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/shivam] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Nov 29 06:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[143404]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 06:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[143404]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 06:25:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[143823]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 06:25:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[143823]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 06:41:32 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/6, but it's already registered
Nov 29 07:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[148081]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 07:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[148081]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 07:30:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[149104]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 07:30:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[149104]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 07:44:41 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/6, but it's already registered
Nov 29 08:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[153341]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 08:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[153341]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 08:30:02 shivam-X510UNR CRON[154580]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 08:30:02 shivam-X510UNR CRON[154580]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 08:37:11 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/6, but it's already registered
Nov 29 09:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[159044]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 09:17:02 shivam-X510UNR CRON[159044]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 09:30:02 shivam-X510UNR CRON[160402]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 09:30:02 shivam-X510UNR CRON[160402]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 09:44:42 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/6, but it's already registered
Nov 29 10:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[164225]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 10:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[164225]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 10:30:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[165465]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 10:30:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[165465]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 10:44:42 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/6, but it's already registered
Nov 29 11:17:02 shivam-X510UNR CRON[169674]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 11:17:02 shivam-X510UNR CRON[169674]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 11:30:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[170798]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 11:30:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[170798]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 11:36:44 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/6, but it's already registered
Nov 29 12:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[175036]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 12:17:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[175036]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 12:19:18 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/2, but it's already registered
Nov 29 12:19:19 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/2, but it's already registered
Nov 29 12:26:43 shivam-X510UNR sudo:   shivam : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/shivam ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/iftop -i wlp2s0
Nov 29 12:26:43 shivam-X510UNR sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 12:28:42 shivam-X510UNR polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:1 successfully authenticated as unix-user:shivam to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.gnome.controlcenter.user-accounts.administration for unix-process:177638:17074536 [gnome-control-center] (owned by unix-user:shivam)
Nov 29 12:30:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[177712]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 12:30:01 shivam-X510UNR CRON[177712]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 12:44:42 shivam-X510UNR gnome-keyring-daemon[1189]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/6, but it's already registered
Nov 29 12:46:09 shivam-X510UNR sudo:   shivam : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/shivam ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh status
Nov 29 12:46:09 shivam-X510UNR sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 12:46:10 shivam-X510UNR sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 12:46:14 shivam-X510UNR sudo:   shivam : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/shivam ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service ssh status
Nov 29 12:46:14 shivam-X510UNR sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 12:46:14 shivam-X510UNR sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 29 12:46:34 shivam-X510UNR sudo:   shivam : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/shivam ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status ssh
Nov 29 12:46:34 shivam-X510UNR sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 29 12:46:34 shivam-X510UNR sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Does this seem suspicious? Google chrome was running on my PC for a whole day, so it might be possible that some of these sessions are related to that. Here I am the one who is running the sudo commands. I don't understand what are the other sessions for. Does this mean someone else also has access to my PC?

Moreover, I also see the following output when I run :

```
sudo iftop -i wlp2s0
```

[image: Output of the above command]

What are these ec2 instances that are communicating with my PC? Not sure about the background process, but nothing was open other than a terminal when I ran that command.

Comment: It looks like you are downloading something (freedesk, amazon).  Does anyone have access to your router?  Was your Windows 10 system compromised?  Dual Boot: One system is OFF so cannot be attacked.

Comment: @John I share the router with my flatmates. I am not sure whether my windows 10 system was compromised or not. I suspect there could be backdoors on my ubuntu OS because I installed it using someone else's Pendrive. They might have given me a version that had backdoors.

Comment: Maybe check your router logs to see if there is traffic you did not generate

Comment: You have multiple reasons to be suspicious and have had no legitimate source for a good starting point. Honestly, I would download a new ISO for Linux (Ubuntu to some distro of choice), verify the ISO's SHA256 hash, write that to a known good flash drive, and completely wipe your system and do a fresh install. At this point you have reasonable suspicion and cause, it is the most logical next step to nuke and pave.

Comment: Nobody has access to your system. The output provided seems perfectly normal. **You have done the Linux equivalent of running netstat and started to worry about foreign addresses.**